# hide button after third onclick

Tags: javascript, button

i made buttons and when you click on them it change from green to red to yellow now i want to add that when you click the button after its color is yellow the button doesnt show anymore.

i tried doing this with:

```
if (color[change > 2]){
            button.style.display = "none";
     }
```

but this doesnt seem to work..is there a way to add this in the function without changing too much of the code?

var color = ["green", "red", "yellow"];

```
function page() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
    //style page
    createButtons(10);
}
page();

function onbuttonclicked(a) {
    var Amount = document.getElementById("button" + a);
    var click = Amount.getAttribute('Color');
    var change = color.indexOf(click);
    Amount.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:' + color[change + 1]);
    Amount.setAttribute('Color', color[change + 1]);

    if (color[change > 2]){
        button.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function set_onclick(amount) {
    for (var a = 1; a < (amount + 1); a++) {
        document.getElementById("button" + a).setAttribute("onclick", "onbuttonclicked(" + a + ")");
    }
}

function createButtons(amount) {
    for (var a = 1; a <(amount + 1); a++) {

        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id = "button" + a;
        button.innerHTML = "button " + a;
        button.setAttribute('Color', color[0]);
        button.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:' + color[0]);
        container.appendChild(button);
    }
    set_onclick(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a variable that increases everytime you click the button and then when the variable reaches a certain value you can delete the button

```
var count=0;
function onButtonClick(){
/your code here
if(count>2){
    /delete button
}
count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let count = -1;
let color = ["green", "red", "yellow"];
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (color[++count]) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = color[count];
  } else {
    this.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: is there a difference between var en let?

Comment: @desit900 replace them as var is ok. var is old fassion way. while let is ES6 standard.

Comment: Is there also a way to make an if/else in my "onbuttonclicked(a)" function and make it hide the button in that way?